# I expanded my disk in vcenter but the 18.04 won't use available space and I think I did something wrong

Tags: partitioning, drive

To clear this up - I added 100g on a Ubuntu 18.04 Server virtual machine.
I followed some guides I found online (being newer to Linux) and was able to see and expand the disk to use the 300 total GB. However, when trying to use resize2fs the - and here's where terminology fails me - logical disk still sees 200g.

Let me add some screenshots.

[cfdisk shows 300g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ohVD.jpg)

However, [resize2fs thinks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCJen.jpg) it's got what it can use already.

And `df -h` just shows the [same old 199](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4vFR.png)

What am I missing here? I need to make sure I can use the full disk - I'm running graylog on this machine and trying to scale it out to fit the ingest load, so I need more space.

Comment: According to your screenshots, you are using volume group. In order to extend logical volume inside volume group, you should use lvextend command.

Comment: @JohnRonald Yeah, sorry - I left that out. I did do an lvextend - the df-h command still shows 200g.

Comment: I actually found a very useful article once I learned more distinction between terms.

https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/

Answer (score 1):

The answer ended up being steps I missed - I found an article that described the parts I missed (namely pvresize /dev/sda3) and followed the steps, which got me where I needed to be.

https://packetpushers.net/ubuntu-extend-your-default-lvm-space/